# Android firebase ml kit barcode dependency duplicate classes

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am using two dependencies for Scanning QR code

**com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0** and
**com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2**,

I am integrating ML Kit library just now, and firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model is already integrated in the app, but i cannot remove the existing api suddenly and want to integrate the new ML kit library as well to check if it's performing better and not creating any issue, but adding both the libraries inside the app gives duplicate class error, how to exclude these particulars classes from ML kit or the other dependency now

Execution failed for task ':app:checkStagingDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.android.libraries.barhopper.RecognitionOptions found in modules jetified-barcode-scanning-17.1.0-runtime (com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0) and jetified-firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model-16.1.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.barhopper.deeplearning.zza found in modules jetified-barcode-scanning-17.1.0-runtime (com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0) and jetified-firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model-16.1.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.barhopper.deeplearning.zzb found in modules jetified-barcode-scanning-17.1.0-runtime (com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0) and jetified-firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model-16.1.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.barhopper.deeplearning.zzc found in modules jetified-barcode-scanning-17.1.0-runtime (com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0) and jetified-firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model-16.1.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.barhopper.deeplearning.zzd found in modules jetified-barcode-scanning-17.1.0-runtime (com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0) and jetified-firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model-16.1.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2)
> Duplicate class com.google.barhopper.deeplearning.zze found in modules jetified-barcode-scanning-17.1.0-runtime (com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0) and jetified-firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model-16.1.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-barcode-model:16.1.2)

Comment: These two libraries are using the same pipeline (barhopper) but in different versions, so even you can exclude some classes to make it compilable, one of them still won't work.

If you really want to test two versions in the same APK, you can try the unbundled version of ML Kit barcode scanning API rather than the bundled one.
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android

Comment: yeah i am using unbundled already, facing issues with it as sometimes the bundle does not get downloaded and app gets installed, so the sdk send ml kit exceptions, that's why wanted to move to bundled one @zhouyi